# What's the name of the technique for allowing elimination of argument in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

The following statements are perfectly OK.

```
var sb = new string[] { "line1", "line2" };
sb.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); 
// same as sb.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

What is the name of this kind of practice not using the argument in the lambda expression?

Thanks,

Comment: I would call that passing in a delegate.

Comment: i'am sorry i don't inderstood

Answer (score 10):

"Method group conversion" is the term you're looking for. It automatically converts a group of methods (overloads) to a delegate.

In this case, `Console.WriteLine` is a group of about 19 different methods all overloaded with the same name. The compiler then figures out if one of those overloads is compatible with an expected delegate (`Action<String>` being the only one). Since there is one that matches, it converts `Console.WriteLine` into `new Action<String>(Console.WriteLine)` for you.

Answer (score 9):

Converting a lambda of the form `Method(x => f(x))` to `Method(f)` is called [eta reduction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion). I don't know whether the C# compiler performs eta reduction internally, but it does support converting a method group (Console.WriteLine in your case) to a delegate type (probably `Action<string>` here).

The C# compiler will wrap the overload `Console.WriteLine(string)` in an `Action<string>` delegate and pass that to your `ForEach` method.

The C# specification defines the rules for converting a method group to a compatible delegate type:

> **6.6 Method group conversions**
>
> An implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from a method group (§7.1) to a
>   compatible delegate type. Given a delegate type D and an expression E
>   that is classified as a method group, an implicit conversion exists
>   from E to D if E contains at least one method that is applicable in
>   its normal form (§7.5.3.1) to an argument list constructed by use of
>   the parameter types and modifiers of D

Answer (score -1):

While both the previous answers are good - and correct - there's an additional answer if you have code like the following:

```
int i = 7;
return () => Foo(i);
```

This is what is called a *closure*, because while the lambda has no parameters, it's enclosing the integer in the parent scope.  When the returned anonymous method is used, it will still be able to use variable i, as if it never went out of scope...and because it's enclosed, it hasn't!

Based on your original question either eta reduction or method group conversion are what you demonstrated.  What your question was *worded* like sounds a bit like closure.